# Dynamic SQL - PDO and MySQL - where to build it?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a web app that takes user selections for many data elements (could be over 50) and dynamically queries against those selections.  The query always runs against one (known) table.  But the WHERE clause changes every time based on user selections.

After a bunch of reading, it seems the logic for creating the query could be done at the PHP level (via PDO prepared statements), or at the DB level (in a MySQL stored procedure).

My question is, which would be the better approach from a performance perspective (caching, code execution, trips across the network, etc)?

It's MySQL 5.6.

So in PHP (dummy example with just 2 parameters rather than 50+):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

$cond = array();
$params = array();

if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $cond[] = "firstname = ?";
    $params[] = $firstname;
}

if (!empty($lastname)) {
    $cond[] = "lastname = ?";
    $params[] = $lastname;
}

if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Or in MySQL, with PHP passing in the params and executing the defined stored proc. (Again, a simplistic dummy example):

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN firstname CHAR(64), IN lastname CHAR(64))
BEGIN

    ...
    ...(skipping over the buildup of the where clause string)
    ...

    SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1 ", @strwhere);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208976/are-stored-procedures-faster-for-simple-queries

Comment: I know there are a ton of stored proc vs inline threads out there, but most seem to approach the question at a general level. The crux of this was for a situation with many dynamic parameters, so I saw it as a bit different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would be the better approach from a performance perspective (caching, code execution, trips across the network, etc)?

Equal.